# codeigniter session is not working on other methods of the same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've made the login controller using a captcha, and using the callback rules to check and validate the captcha input.

So, I tried to send captcha variable to another method in the same controller using the session.

When I echo the session in another function, it is not working. It works only when I try to echo it in the same function.

Here's the code:

**1. Login Function**

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->auth->is_logged_in() === TRUE)
    {
        redirect(base_url()."dashboard");
    }

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required|callback_check_captcha');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $cap                = $this->created_captcha();
        $data['cap_img']    = $cap['image'];
        $data['title']      = 'Form Login Administrator';

        $this->session->set_userdata('captcha', $cap['word']);
        $sess = $this->session->userdata('captcha');

        echo ' <br/> FIRST SESSION : '.$sess . ' --- ';

        $this->load->view('form-login', $data);

    }
    else
    {
        $check_login = $this->auth->do_login($username,$password);

        if($check_login == FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Your username or password wrong, please repeat again !!!');
            redirect(base_url().'login');
        }
        else
        {
            $lastlogin = $this->dbm->update('users', array('userid'=>$this->session->userdata('userid')), array('lastlogin'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) );

            $this->session->unset_userdata('captcha');

            redirect(base_url().'dashboard');   

        }
    }
}
```

**2. Check capthca Function**

```
public function check_captcha($input)
{
    echo '<br/> SECOND SESSION : '. $this->session->userdata('captcha') . ' --- ' .
         '<br/> POST INPUT : '.$input.' --- ';  

    if($input === $this->session->userdata('captcha')) 
    {

        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'you input the wrong %s!'); 

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I've tried to put the session library in the constructor, but still the same.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
}
```

Am i making a mistake here? please help, thanks.

**Edit :**
this happen only in chrome browser.

Comment: where you load `form_validation` library?

Comment: it loaded in autoload.php in config directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting captcha session in `check_captcha` method because your captcha session being created only when form not validated.

Put following lines of code before `if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)..`

```
    $cap                = $this->created_captcha();
    $data['cap_img']    = $cap['image'];
    $data['title']      = 'Form Login Administrator';

    $this->session->set_userdata('captcha', $cap['word']);
```

Comment: it doesn't work, this session issue only happen when i using chrome